# Difference between biblatex [style=chicago] and biblatex-chicago packages?

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I would like to know the difference between `\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}` and `\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex}`?

Comment: Have a look at the package file `biblatex-chicago.sty` and you will see the difference. The main differences are the passed options of `biblatex`, the definition of the environment `thebibliography` and the option `nomark`.

Comment: Thanks. They both have problems with the `cbytranslator` and `cbyeditor` fields. I am not quite sure why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quoting from section 5.5.1 of the `biblatex-chicago` manual (a full reading of this section is recommended):

> [...] With early versions of `biblatex-chicago`, the standard
>   way of loading the package was via a call to `biblatex`, e.g.:
>
> ```
> \usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,strict,backend=bibtex8,%
> babel=other,bibencoding=inputenc]{biblatex}
> ```
>
> Now, the default way to load the style, and one that will in the vast
>   majority of standard cases produce the same results as the old
>   invocation, will look like this:
>
> ```
> \usepackage[authordate,strict,backend=bibtex8,babel=other,%
> bibencoding=inputenc]{biblatex-chicago}
> ```
>
> If you read through `biblatex-chicago.sty`, you’ll see that it sets a
>   number of `biblatex` options aimed at following the Chicago
>   specification, as well as setting a few formatting variables intended
>   as reasonable defaults [...]. Some parts of this specification,
>   however, are plainly more “suggested” than “required,” and indeed many
>   publishers, while adopting the main skeleton of the Chicago style in
>   citations, nonetheless maintain their own house styles to which the
>   defaults I have provided do not conform.
>
> If you only need to change one or two parameters, this can easily be
>   done by putting different options in the call to `biblatex-chicago` or
>   redefining other formatting variables in the preamble, thereby
>   overriding the package defaults. If, however, you wish more
>   substantially to alter the output of the package[...], then you may
>   want to revert to the old style of invocation above. You’ll lose all
>   the definitions in `biblatex-chicago.sty`[...]
>
> What you *will not* lose is the ability to call the package options
>   `annotation`, `strict`, `short`, and `noibid` [...], in case these
>   continue to be useful to you when constructing your own modifications.
>   There’s very little code, therefore, actually in
>   `biblatex-chicago.sty`[...]

Comment: it looks to me that calling `\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}` is now (July 20, 2012) broken with version 2.0 of the biblatex package while calling `\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}` is no problem.

Comment: Just to note that in 2015 `\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}` is the correct way to invoke the package.