# Problem with biblatex-chicago and bibliographies

Tags: biblatex, sharelatex, biblatex-chicago

This is probably a problem with an easy solution, but I am very new to using LaTeX and I have not been able to find the solution.

Anyhow, I am working in Sharelatex on a thesis, and I am using a chicago-authordate-ish bibliography version in biblatex. The problem grew out of me trying to add a newspaper article to my bibliography. When using the following code I could not get the date of the article to show up in the bibliography:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chicago-authordate,sorting=nyt,cmsdate=both,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{blakeslee1947,
  title={'Flying Saucers' Called Forerunners of the New Atomic Folklore},
  author={Howard W. Blakeslee},
  journal={The Washington Post},
  pages={B2},
  date={1947-07-20},
  entrysubtype={newspaper},
}
@book{Dorson1971a,
author={Richard M. Dorson},
title={American folklore},
publisher={University of Chicago Press},
address={Chicago},
year={1971},
origdate={1959},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} 
\begin{document} 
text \footnote{\cite{blakeslee1947}; \cite[][p. 78]{Dorson1971a}}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Using this code the output became:

[image]

When searching for a solution to the missing date in the reference to the article from the Washington post I found an article ([Difference between biblatex [style=chicago] and biblatex-chicago packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59222/difference-between-biblatex-style-chicago-and-biblatex-chicago-packages)) stating that the proper way to call on this style would be like this:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authordate,sorting=nyt,cmsdate=both,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{blakeslee1947,
  title={'Flying Saucers' Called Forerunners of the New Atomic Folklore},
  author={Howard W. Blakeslee},
  journal={The Washington Post},
  pages={B2},
  date={1947-07-20},
  entrysubtype={newspaper},
}
@book{Dorson1971a,
author={Richard M. Dorson},
title={American folklore},
publisher={University of Chicago Press},
address={Chicago},
year={1971},
origdate={1959},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} 
\begin{document} 
text \footnote{\cite{blakeslee1947}; \cite[][p. 78]{Dorson1971a}}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This proved to amend the problem with the missing date, but I do now instead get a different layout of the bibliography and the footnotes, is there any easy way to get the style of the first example back without having to revert back to the first code-example?:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you keep `style=chicago-authordate` in the second code block?

Comment: Your second printout, doesn't seem at all to be produced by `\footnote{\cite{blakeslee1947}; \cite[][p. 78]{Dorson1971a}}` on an `authordate` style. Your second example trows an error to me, but if I give just `authordate` as an option to `biblatex-chicago` (that is, not `style=authordate`, just `authordate`), I get results very similar to your first printout, with the newspaper date. Which seems to be what you want.

Comment: @cfr there is sadly no difference in the output

Comment: @gusbrs, when I try that the dates for the newspaper disappears again for me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a Sharelatex account to test it. But the only change I made was that one, and got what I think are your expected results. And I still don't see how `\cite{blakeslee1947}` could have produced "Howard W. Blakeslee, “’Flying Saucers’ Called Forerunners of the New Atomic Folk-lore,” The Washington Post, July 20, 1947, B2" etc in `authordate` style. Which makes me think your compilation might be stumbling on some kind of error (and thus not completing).

Comment: I think I understood how the result came about. `biblatex-chicago` does not recognize `style` as an option, and thus reverts to the default, which is `notes`. That's why you get a notes-like citation with that "option". Do you get any errors when compiling? Still I cannot help much as to why the date goes missing with `authordate`, as I observe here a different behavior.

Comment: @gusbrs Checked now and I do get 4 error messages: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/biblatex-chicago.sty, line 98

Package keyval Error: style undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.98 ...liographyOptions\expandafter{\cms@options}
                                                  
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Comment: @gusbrs and also: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/chicago-notes.cbx

Package biblatex Warning: '\name' is deprecated in sorting specifications, please use '\field'.

Comment: @gusbrs: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/chicago-notes.cbx

Package biblatex Warning: '\list' is deprecated in sorting specifications, please use '\field'.

Comment: @gusbrs, and finally it just says: "Writing file `./bibliography.bib'." (I was wondering if that was a problem since I have a similarly named bib-file in another project there. I just abbreviated a new file with the preamble and a short bibliography to more easily show the code)

Comment: @gusbrs sorry for loads of comments. In the first example I get this error: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/chicago-dates-common.cbx

Package biblatex Warning: 'labeldate' option used to determine whether to provide label date fields and extrayear field is renamed to 'labeldateparts', setting this instead. This option is now used to set the format of the labeldate.

Comment: So you do get a style undefined error. That means you were not loading the `authordate` style at all, for the default of `biblatex-chicago` is `notes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking again `biblatex-chicago`'s documentation, and what it says about the case is the following:

> The *Manual* now suggests that, no matter which citation style you are
>   using, it is “usually sufficient to cite newspaper and magazine
>   articles entirely within the text” (15.47). This involves giving the
>   title of the journal and the full date of publication in a
>   parenthetical reference, including any other information in the main
>   text (14.206), thereby obviating the need to present such an entry in
>   the list of references. To utilize this method in the author-date
>   styles, in addition to a `magazine` entrysubtype , you’ll need to place
>   `cmsdate=full` into the options field, including `skipbib` there as well
>   to stop the entry printing in the list of references. If the entry
>   only contains a `date` and `journaltitle` that’s enough, but if it’s a
>   fuller entry also containing an author then you’ll also need
>   `useauthor=false` in the options field. Other surplus fields will be
>   ignored. (See `osborne:poison`.)

So it seems that the problem with the missing date is that `biblatex-chicago` doesn't expect to print it in the bibliography. (Still, for me it prints the year by the author, and month and date later in parentheses).
Anyway, following the documentation, you could use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{blakeslee1947,
    title={`Flying Saucers' Called Forerunners of the New Atomic Folklore},
    author={Howard W. Blakeslee},
    journaltitle={The Washington Post},
    pages={B2},
    date={1947-07-20},
    entrysubtype={magazine},
    options={cmsdate=full,skipbib,useauthor=false},
}
@book{Dorson1971a,
    author={Richard M. Dorson},
    title={American folklore},
    publisher={University of Chicago Press},
    address={Chicago},
    year={1971},
    origdate={1959},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} 
\begin{document} 
    text \footcite[78]{Dorson1971a} \footcite[5]{blakeslee1947}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]
[image]

I'm not sure that's what you intended, but it seems to be what the current Chicago Manual favors, and what `biblatex-chicago` implements in practice.

EDIT: what I mean by "make it work for you, even when not following the style's strict guidelines". Try, for example (or something other in similar lines):

```
@misc{blakeslee1947,
    title={`Flying Saucers' Called Forerunners of the New Atomic Folklore},
    author={Howard W. Blakeslee},
    titleaddon={The Washington Post, 20 July, 1947, p. B2},
    date={1947},
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does indeed seem to be in line with the manual. I might have to consider changing to another style completely since I am pretty sure I will be demanded to list all references in the bibliography. I'll leave it unsolved as of now in case anyone else has an idea on how to tweak this into working.

Comment: Well, if the Chicago style is required of you explicitly, then it should not be a problem, for it is covered. But if you need an author-date style and chose Chicago for some other reason, you might consider `biblatex`'s `authoryear` style.

Comment: Still, if you remove `skipbib` from the entry option, it will be printed in the bibliography. What I'm saying is that, most likely, you can also use `biblatex-chicago` and make it work for you, even when not following the style's strict guidelines. But to set better what your style requirements are, would be a good starting point for you.

Comment: I think they are not that explicit about which style they prefer, it's a washed down version of Chicago or authoryear that comes closest I guess. I have written in the Chicago style for books before so I pretty much just choose that one out of habit and stylistic preference :)

Comment: @Erik, see the edit. Perhaps that's the kind of thing that will sort it out for you.

Comment: Thanks! I think I can work it out from this! On a second thought I think your first solution in just referring to the manual of style might very well be working fine for me if I can argue for the practice.

Comment: @Erik, I do believe that's the wisest. Choose a style (which is made to be consistent), and stray away from it only if there is good reason to do so.