# Why is \textcite not producing “author (year)”?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}

% BIBLIOGRAPHY SETTINGS

\addbibresource{Ref.bib}

% DOCUMENT

\begin{document}

See \textcite{shapley_62}.

\raggedright
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Coupled with this Ref.bib

```
@article{shapley_62,
    title={Simple games: An outline of the descriptive theory},
    author={Lloyd Stowell {Shapley}},
    journal={Behavioral Science},
    volume={7},
    number={1},
    pages={59--66},
    year={1962},
    doi={10.1002/bs.3830070104}
}
```

The output is this one:

[image]

It was my understanding that using `\textcite{}` produced “author (year)”. However, it doesn’t. So, two questions:

1. Why is `\textcite` not producing “author (year)”?
2. How to get “author (year)” while keeping the bibliography style I have chosen?

Comment: I compiled it and it works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The styles of the `biblatex-chicago` bundle are a bit special: They should not be loaded via `\usepackage[style=<style>]{biblatex}`. Instead you should load them via the wrapper package `biblatex-chicago`. This wrapper package sets up a few options and other things that would not be set up if you were to load the style directly via `biblatex`.

This is also discussed in the [`biblatex-chicago` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf) once in the *Quickstart* section on p. 3 and in much more detail in §4.5.1 *Loading the Style* [for `notes`] (pp. 91-92) or §5.5.1 *Loading the Styles* [for `authordate`] (p. 171)

The following MWE works fine

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber, authordate]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{shapley_62,
  title   = {Simple games: An outline of the descriptive theory},
  author  = {Lloyd Stowell Shapley},
  journal = {Behavioral Science},
  volume  = {7},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {59--66},
  year    = {1962},
  doi     = {10.1002/bs.3830070104}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
See \textcite{shapley_62}.

\raggedright
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: See Shapley (1962).]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59222/35864